# Retrieve data from while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on book engine .I am done with all query of retriving data from database to check availability of room in hotel.When i  run this query .

```
 while($rooms=mysqli_fetch_array($retrive_result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img width='100' height='100' src='".$rooms['image']."'></td>";

    echo "<td>". $rooms['room_no']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $rooms['type']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $rooms['rate']."</td>";
    echo "<td>". "<a href='guest_details.php' class='btn btn-default'>BOOK</a>"."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    }
```

It show the available room .like this

```
image    room_no  room_type  rate    book_room
image1   12        1bk       1000    book
image1   13        2bk       2000    book
image1   14        3bk       3000    book
image1   15        4bk       4000    book
```

When I click on book in book_room column then it redirect to next page .I want the room_no,room_type,rate (ex:12,1bk,1000) value in next page to show the value.
please help me to find out the solution .what i do

Comment: your question is not clear . Can you please elaborate ??

Comment: When I click on book in book_room column then it redirect to next page.I want correspondance book row value (for example when i click on first row book the value 12,1bk,1000) value in next page when page redirect to next page. to display value in next page

Comment: Mr SearchAndResQ..how to display value in second page

Comment: like that? index.php?room_no=12&room_type=1bk&rate=1000

Answer (score 1):

Pass values as parameter in url and use `$_GET` on `guest_details.php` to get values.
like `$_GET['room_no']`

```
while ($rooms = mysqli_fetch_array($retrive_result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img width='100' height='100' src='" . $rooms['image'] . "'></td>";

    echo "<td>" . $rooms['room_no'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rooms['type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rooms['rate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<a href='guest_details.php?room_no=".$rooms['room_no']."&type=".$rooms['type']."' class='btn btn-default'>BOOK</a>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Check the image**

[image]

Comment: what is the issue you are getting? can you update your code with what you have done.

Comment: and i also try by getting it in $_GET['room_no'] but it not display any value only show on url like     http://localhost/booking-system/guest_details.php?room_no=

Comment: "<td>". "<td>". "<a href='guest_details.php?room_no='".$rooms['room_no']."'&type='"
                        .$rooms['type']."' class='btn btn-default'>BOOK</a>"."</td>";   my update code

Comment: its working pretty fine. check the image I have updated.

Comment: I didnt get any images